# Eclipse Hono - Installation (Version 1.1.1)

Tags: eclipse-hono, eclipse-iot

I am not sure on the exact instructions to install Hono 1.1.1 locally. Following the documentation , I was able to build the project with maven but I am not sure on how to proceed.

I was using version 0.9 before in which I managed to run Hono using docker swarm by running the swarm_deploy.sh script that was located in the deploy folder after building the project with maven. Currently in Hono 1.1.1 in the deploy folder we have services.sh instead of swarm_deploy.sh.

I would like to know, how could I run the docker swarm as it was in version 0.9? Are there any major drawbacks from this approach?

Note: I am looking for a simple way to install  Hono locally as its a small experimental project and not aiming at a full scalable version yet such as using Kubernetes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but we no longer support deployment to plain Docker Swarm. You shouldn't have any issues installing Hono 1.1.1 using the Helm chart to a local [minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/) or [kind](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind) (single node) cluster, though. There is no big difference in resource consumption compared to plain Docker Swarm, in particular if you are using kind.

Using this approach there also is no need to compile Hono from source. Just follow the [Hono chart's README](https://github.com/eclipse/packages/tree/master/charts/hono).